# HTML Canvas Not Displaying Correctly When Resized to Fit Parent Div with 'offsetWidth'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a sketchpad application using html canvas and javascript (trying to stay away from jQuery). The canvas needs to be responsive and I've found several methods to do so, but each one stretches out the canvas and makes the sketchpad unusable. It's hard to explain without seeing the problem. Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/loudenwilhelm/pen/mqZqxp?editors=1111). Try drawing inside the canvas and you'll see what I'm talking about. The current method I'm using to resize the canvas incorporates `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` like so:

```
var sketchpadContainer = [
    document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth, 
    document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight]

var canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

canvas.style.height = sketchpadContainer[1] + "px";
canvas.style.width = sketchpadContainer[0] + "px";
```

Is there a way to make the canvas responsive while at the same time keeping the dimensions of the sketch intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS width and height properties are NOT the same as the width and height attributes on a Canvas element.

If you absolutely need to use css to set width/height, keep a scale factor of your default canvas size, then multiple the target x and y positions of your mouse position by the inverse of the x/y  scale factors (or just divide the target position by them).

Using css to resize your canvas is a bit too hacky imo (and will leave your lines blurry), I highly recommend you instead simlpy change with width/height attributes of your canvas and use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale()` to change the size of your lines (A scale factor will still need to be used to calculate your true mouse pos, however)

Simply change

```
canvas.style.height = sketchpadContainer[1] + "px";
canvas.style.width = sketchpadContainer[0] + "px";
```

to

```
canvas.height = sketchpadContainer[1];
canvas.width = sketchpadContainer[0];
```

Apply `CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale()` when you first get your context, and then do as I mentioned above. (`ctx.lineTo(x,y);` -> `ctx.lineTo(x/scaleFactorX,y/scaleFactorY);` & `lastX=x;` -> `lastX=x/scaleFactorX;`)

I.E See [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeEQvr?editors=1111)